# Need software for real time gps tracking

Tags: gps

I have a proposal in which I need to recommend a software package/monitoring system that will aid in the real time monitoring of a set fishing vessels, fish catch, and the fishermen while at sea.

The project is in its preliminary stage and no decisions have been made as to hardware, software and methodology.

The plan:
1. Host the application in the cloud via an Amazon Web Services account with the Ubuntu OS.
2. The boats will be outfitted with a GPS device and the fishermen will have a smart phone
3. Real time collected will be GPS and SMS
4. The data will stored in a geo-database (like cartodb)
5. leaflet for mapping software
6. Other related data will be manually

My preference is to use open source software

Any hardware and software suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: What OS should it be running on (tracking device, monitoring device)? How should the monitoring be done (e.g. how should the data come from the tracking device to the monitoring device: mobile data, SMS, …)? Please [edit] your post and add some more details (for a guide, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  More details added

Comment: How far out will the vessels be? Trying to use cell phone signals won't work when the cell towers have disappeared below the horizon ;-) Sounds like only satellite communication will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The OS question is still not addressed (if you're open to "anything", as no hardware was yet acquired, please point that out explicitly). From the details, it could be Android/iOS/Windows/Fire*/whatever – and you gave no details for the "receiving end". If (GPS) data is shared via SMS, you either need a gateway or some smartphone here as well. As it currently stands, I'd almost say your request goes beyond what this site is for: we do no *hardware* recommendations, especially not that detailed.

Comment: Jan It is the artisanal (small craft) fishing industry. So the boats will not be going too far from the shore.  The real time data will be mainly from the GPS units.

Comment: Izzy... I am waiting for information on the specifications of the hardware they plan to use and will add it to my original post. I don't understand what you mean by "the OS question is still not address"  Are you talking about the software for the GPS unit?  The OpenGTS software Pathum suggested, looks interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you give a try on this it's called [OpenGTS](http://opengts.sourceforge.net/),This software is a full featured web-based GPS tracking system for your fleet of vehicles. It supports OpenLayers and other map providers, detail/summary Reporting, and various GPS tracking devices.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Motorola Moto-G phone with a built in GPS. There is a free application called **[My Tracks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.maps.mytracks&hl=en)** from Google that will track the phones location using the GPS and share the data to the cloud. This should work on any Android phone with a GPS and current hardware/software.

This does not implement all of your requirements but it does much of it.