# Recording GPS coordinates in Windows using USB GPS antenna

Tags: maps, gps, gis

I'm looking for a Free/Open-Source program for recording GPS coordinates from an external GPS antenna plugged into a laptop via USB and display them on a map in real-time. Must be able to work offline as cell coverage is unreliable. Ability to label/annotate the points would be a plus.

Tried using Google Maps & Google MyMaps to place pins using a cell phone, but whenever I have poor cell signal I find that the pins are off by as much as 50 ft.

There are a myriad of GIS programs out there, but its not clear to me which ones support USB GPS antennas.

Comment: I've tried Google Earth Pro, but the map won't stay zoomed in far enough to confirm that the pin is in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

OK so first off, verifying your position using Google Earth photos is fraught with danger. Do you know what the accuracy of those photos are? Different photos at different times have different accuracies and are just unreliable.

Most GPS loggers will record the accuracy of the GPS coords that they are capturing, use this to get an idea about how accurate the readings are

Secondly, to answer your question

- MyTracks from Google
- openGTS - http://opengts.sourceforge.net/

That second link is probably the best example of an Open source project that I could find.

Additional discussion here
[Need software for real time gps tracking](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13524/need-software-for-real-time-gps-tracking?rq=1)